# iOS app audio stops when screen auto-locks after upgrading app to xcode 8

Tags: ios, audio

I have an app that has been published on the iTunes App Store, and it has background mode enabled for audio.

After updating to XCode 8, I published an update for my app, after which I've found that the app stops playing whenever the screen locks. I had not made any changes to background play otherwise. Not sure if the behavior or coding requirements changed for iOS 9+

Here's what my code does:

```
App plist file:

    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>


AudioController.m

-(void)setBackgroundPlay:(bool)backgroundPlay
{
    NSLog(@"setBackgroundPlay %d", backgroundPlay);
    AVAudioSession *mySession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *audioSessionError = nil;

    if (backgroundPlay) {

        // Assign the Playback category to the audio session.
        [mySession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                         error: &audioSessionError];

        OSStatus propertySetError = 0;

        UInt32 allowMixing = true;

        propertySetError = AudioSessionSetProperty (
                                                    kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,  // 1
                                                    sizeof (allowMixing),                                 // 2
                                                    &allowMixing                                          // 3
                                                    );
        if (propertySetError != 0) {
            NSLog (@"Error setting audio property MixWithOthers");
        }

    } else {
        // Assign the Playback category to the audio session.
        [mySession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                         error: &audioSessionError];
    }
    if (audioSessionError != nil) {
        NSLog (@"Error setting audio session category.");
    }
}
```

The audio does continue playing when I minimize the app, and it continues playing until the screen auto-locks. Whenever the screen turns on (like when a notification is received), audio resumes, and then shuts off when the screen goes black.

As mentioned, this stuff used to work, and seems to have changed behavior after update to Xcode 8/iOS 9.

I've tried searching the forum and other places for people experiences similar issues, but haven't been able to locate anything.

Any suggestions, or a fresh pair of eyes looking at this would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Sridhar

Comment: Do you have background audio enabled in the Capabilities section of the project settings?

Comment: Yes, I do! I managed to find the problem and the solution, which I'll add below.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I found the problem! Everything was ok with regard to how I had setup background audio.

The key giveaway was looking at the console of the device when the screen lock had turned on:

Jan 17 11:03:59 My-iPad Talanome[1179] : kAudioUnitErr_TooManyFramesToProcess : inFramesToProcess=4096, mMaxFramesPerSlice=1156

A little searching led me to this Technical note - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1606/_index.html

The key is this --

```
// set the mixer unit to handle 4096 samples per slice since we want to keep rendering during screen lock
UInt32 maxFPS = 4096;
AudioUnitSetProperty(mMixer, kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0,
                     &maxFPS, sizeof(maxFPS));
```

I had not set my maxFramesPerSlice, and so it was defaulting to 1156, which was too small for when the auto-lock is on (which is 4096). Setting the maxFramesPerSlice to 4096 in my audio initialization ensured that I have enough for when the screen locks.

Hope this helps others who may face similar issues!

-Sridhar

Comment: Thank you for saving my app!